# Ask For a .htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess

```
I have two websites(a.com and b.com)
When I hit these type of file
js|css|gif|jpg|png|ico|txt|swf|mp3|pdf|ps|wav|mid|midi|flv|zip|rar|gz|tar|bmp
E.G. http://a.com/123/b.jpg -> http://b.com/123/b.jpg
     http://a.com/256/c.jpg -> http://b.com/256/c.jpg

How can I do it?
Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

In the .htaccess file in DocumentRoot directory of a.com host put this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(js|css|gif|jpg|png|ico|txt|swf|mp3|pdf|ps|wav|mid|midi|flv|zip|rar|gz|tar|bmp)$ http://b.com/$1.$2 [R,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule into your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\.(js|css|gif|jpg|png|ico|txt|swf|mp3|pdf|ps|wav|mid|midi|flv|zip|rar|gz|tar|bmp)
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://b.com/$1
```